# Не открываются *.onion сайты (Could not open *.onion sites)

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, vidalia

Translation attempt: I installed the Vidalia bundle (Vidalia, Tor, Polipo) and am not able to load onion sites (hidden services). Why is that?

[image: введите здесь описание Изображения]
[image: введите здесь описание изображения]

Comment: Hidden services often appear and disappear. So can you open this [sample site](http://duskgytldkxiuqc6.onion/) or [Duck Duck Go](http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/)?